# How to read an XML input file, manipulate some nodes (remove and rename some) and write the output to a new XML output file?

Tags: xml, r

I need to read an XML file from internet and re-shape it.
Here is the XML file and the code I have so far.

```
library(XML)
url='http://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT00001400?displayxml=true'  
doc = xmlParse(url,useInternalNode=TRUE)
```

I was able to use some functions within the XML package with sucess(e.g., getNodeSet), but I am not an expert and there are some examples on the internet but I was not able to crack this problem myself. I also know some XPath but this was 4 years ago and I am not an expert on sapply and similar functions.

But my goal is this:

1. I need to remove a whole set of XML children branches about location, for example: `<location>  ... anything </location>`.  There can be multiple nodes with location data. I simply don't need that detail in the output.  The XML file above always complies to an XSD schema. The root node is called `<clinical_study>`.
2. The resulted simplified file should be written into a new XML file called "data-changed.xml".
3. I also need to rename and move one branch from old nested place of

   `<eligibility>
      <criteria>
        <textblock>
          Inclusion criteria are xyz
        </textblock/>...`
4. In new output ("data-changed.xml") the structure should say a different XML node and be directly under root node:

   `<eligibility_criteria> 
      Inclusion criteria are xyz
   </eligibility_criteria>`

So I need to:

- read the XML into memory
- manipulate the tree (prune it somewhere)
- move some XML nodes to a new place and under a new name and
- write the resulting XML output file.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated?

Also, if you know about a nice (recent !) tutorial on XML parsing within R (or book chapter which tackles it, please share the reference). (I read the vignettes by Duncan and these are too advanced (too concise)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code to remove all location nodes:

```
r <- xmlRoot(doc)
removeNodes(r[names(r) == "location"])
```

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer to your question on how to apply an xpath to an xml file is to use `xpathSApply`.  This works for me:

```
library(XML)
nct_url <- "http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00112281?resultsxml=true"
xml_doc <- xmlParse(nct_url, useInternalNode=TRUE)
elig_path <- "/clinical_study/eligibility/criteria/textblock" 
elig_text <- xpathSApply(xml_doc, elig_path, xmlValue)
```

I'm doing some work with clinicaltrials.gov XML files, using R and its XML package.  The package is tricky, and I only partially understand it.  I've written a function to help deal with missing nodes in the XML:

```
findbyxpath <- function(xmlfile, xpath) {
  xmldoc <- xmlParse(xmlfile)
  result <- try(xpathSApply(xmldoc, xpath, xmlValue))
  if(length(result) == 0) { # check for empty list, returned if node not found
    return("")
  } else {
    return(result)
  }
}
```

I use xml in files downloaded from clinicaltrials.gov ahead of time, so `file` is one of those. Then my example would instead look like this:

```
file <- "NCT00112281.xml"
elig_text <- findbyxpath(file, elig_path)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is what XSLT is designed for. It's a little bit of a learning curve, but once mastered, it's by far the most effective way of doing this kind of work. And you can translate your English rules directly into XSLT rules: for example, your first rule that says strip all location elements and their children is simply:

```
<xsl:template match="location"/>
```

and the rule about moving content to be under the new root node might be:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <new-root-node>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//eligibility/criteria"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </new-root-node>
</xsl:template>
```

This is just a flavour of course - you haven't specified your transformation rules precisely enough to translate into accurate code.

Comment: OK. I wrote some XSLT in the past. It does not fully solve my problem though. I googled for native XSLT library for R and was not able to find one. Only via System command I might invoke some external XSLT parser. It still requires a lot of R code which I am not able to write.

Do you know how to achieve in R something like this:
 outputXML <- Process(XMLfile,withTHISxsltFile)